# How to combine low and high poly mesh

Tags: mesh, sculpting, remesh

I split my head from my body so I could remesh it with a higher density. What is the best way of merging them together again, after I'm done with the head? (same for hands and legs)

Or I'll maybe ask this differently, what's the best workflow for making the high detail mesh which will later be baked onto a base mesh?

Added to that I can't sculpt on a more than 5mil faces mesh without Blender lagging. So I somehow need to split things like the head into separate objects so Blender doesn't start lagging.

Comment: Why not remesh the whole model? Do you want to 3D print the model or could you use normal maps?

Comment: If I would remesh the entire model it would have a way to high poly count, if I would want to keep it on the level I used for the face

Comment: You could merge the head and the body with the boolean modifier. The remesher creates (topology-wise) an ugly mesh. And the merged result won't be pretty either. That's why I've asked what you plan to do with the model.

Comment: I'll maybe ask this differently, what's the best workflow for making the high detail mesh which will later be baked onto a base mesh. Added to that I can't sculpt on a more than 5mil faces mesh without blender lagging. So I somehow need to split things like the head into separate objects so blender doesn't start lagging.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to bake a normal map and keep the polycount low while you sculpt the details there is no need to combine the high poly with the low poly mesh, is there?

First, try if the *Multires* modifier works for your whole model. It can handle high polycounts very well.

If the performance is still bad

- UV unwrap the model
- duplicate it
- separate the head, hand/arm, and legs at the seams
- add *Multires* modifiers to each part and sculpt the details for the parts
- bake the normal map for the parts. The first time when you bake (for example the head's normal) leave the *[X] Clear Image* checked. For the next part (the hand for example) uncheck the checkbox. This way the normals for the hand are added to the image and the already baked normals for the head will not get deleted. Repeat this for all parts.
- use the baked normal map for the original low poly mesh

[image: bake options]

Comment: I'm actively using the multires, but the uv thing is quite interesting, thanks